# Set metadata for all objects in a Google Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to set `Content-Type` metadata to `image/jpeg` for *all* objects of a Google Storage bucket.

How to do this?

Answer (score 16):

Using `gsutil` and its [`setmeta`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta) command:

`gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type:image/jpeg" gs://YOUR_BUCKET/**/*.jpg`

Use the `-m` to activate a parallel update, in case you have a lot of objects.

The `/**/*` pattern will perform a recursive search on any folders that you may have on your bucket.

Comment: This only covers objects without forward slash characters in the name.  If you also want to operate on objects named like `picture/in/some/folder.jpg`, then you should use a recursive glob pattern: `gs://YOUR_BUCKET/**/*.jpg`

Comment: Thanks @mhouglum ! I'll add it to my answer.